# Token authentication with aspnet web api 2.0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, token, asp.net-web-api2

I'm new to web api, and I noticed that session isn't supported there. I found  that tokens are the best way for authentication, but I couldn't figure out how to implement that in my application. Everything I found wasn't helpful and too much complex for me.

Isn't there something simple like this?

```
Public Sub Login(<FromBody()> ByVal Email As String, <FromBody()> ByVal Password As String)
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[Login]"
    cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Email
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Password
    cmd.Connection.Open()
    Dim rd As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If rd.HasRows Then
        While rd.Read()
            **GENERATE A TOKEN AND LINK TO rd.Item("IdUser")**
            **Return TOKEN**
            (previously I would use Session("id") = rd.Item("IdUser"))
        End While
        Return "Ok"
    Else
        ...
    End If
    cmd.Connection.Close()
    Return True
End Sub
```

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security

Comment: Ok I'm starting to understand, in your link I found this
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication
Tell me if I understand..that class is called every http request and it gets the username and password from the authentication header, so with this I should send username and password, not the token right? So now I just have to find a way to generate a token, send to client and save to database right?

Comment: I Understand how authentication and token works, but I still dont understand how to implement it all the resources I find are too much intricated and dont fit with my solution.
I just need how to generate a token in my login api and how to check it before every protected api in VB

Comment: you could generate a base64 encoded string using the credentials,and ask users to pass it on every call.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just get something working (thanks Amit Kumar Ghosh), hope will be useful for someone

This in App_start

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Net.Http.Headers
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.Web.Security

Namespace Glossario.MessageHandler
    Public Class BasicAuthenticationMessageHandler
        Inherits DelegatingHandler
        Protected Overrides Function SendAsync(request As HttpRequestMessage, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)
            Dim myCredentials As Credentials = Nothing
            Dim identity As GenericIdentity = Nothing

            If (request.Headers.Authorization IsNot Nothing) Then
                myCredentials = ExtractCredentials(request.Headers.Authorization)
                If IsValidUser(myCredentials) Then
                    identity = New GenericIdentity(myCredentials.UserName, "Basic")
                    request.GetRequestContext().Principal = New GenericPrincipal(identity, New String(-1) {})
                End If
            End If
            Return MyBase.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
        End Function

        Private Function ExtractCredentials(authHeader As AuthenticationHeaderValue) As Credentials
            Dim myCredentials As Credentials = Nothing
            Try
                If authHeader.Scheme = "Basic" Then
                    Dim encodedUserPass = authHeader.Parameter.Trim()
                    Dim encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")
                    Dim userPass = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUserPass))
                    Dim parts = userPass.Split(":".ToCharArray())

                    myCredentials = New Credentials()
                    myCredentials.UserName = parts(0)
                    myCredentials.Password = parts(1)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                myCredentials = Nothing
            End Try
            Return myCredentials
        End Function

        Private Function IsValidUser(myCredentials As Credentials) As Boolean
            Dim result As Boolean = False

            If (myCredentials IsNot Nothing) Then
                    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[Login]" 'CHANGE WITH YOUR OWN CODE
                    cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = MyCredentials.UserName
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = MyCredentials.Password
                    cmd.Connection.Open()
                    Dim rd As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    If rd.HasRows Then
                        While rd.Read()
                            Result = True
                        End While
                    End If
                    cmd.Connection.Close()
            End If
            Return result
        End Function

        Private Class Credentials
            Public Property UserName() As String
            Public Property Password() As String
        End Class
    End Class
End Namespace
```

in global.asax Protected Sub Application_Start()

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(New Glossario.MessageHandler.BasicAuthenticationMessageHandler())
```

Comment: In case of a HTTP 401, it is responsibility of the server to return a challenge token in response that had to be sent in subsequent requests by clients.